# Tizen SDK: Can't find variable: tizen

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-emulator

I'm trying to create a web-application using Tizen SDK. When I launch the app everything is fine but when I press a "Back" button on emulator nothing happens and I see a message:

> 55435/js/main.js:9:ReferenceError: Can't find variable: tizen

I looked at `main.js` and there's a code:

```js
//Initialize function
var init = function () {
    // TODO:: Do your initialization job
    console.log("init() called");

    // add eventListener for tizenhwkey
    document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
        if(e.keyName == "back") {
            tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit(); // HERE IS THE ERROR
        }
    });
};
$(document).bind('pageinit', init);
```

A simple `alert(window.tizen)` said that it is `undefined` so I thought that some js file wasn't attached to project. Here are scripts that was generated by Tizen SDK:

```html
<script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw-libs.js"></script>
<script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw.js" data-framework-theme="tizen-white"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

I think some script should be added but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it is working now, but I found the solution. I just changed the workspace and it worked.

Comment: Thanks to you, that helped

Answer (score 4):

The 'tizen' namespace seems to disappear on anything but the files directly in the .wgt.  So if it's loading a webpage from somewhere else, the 'tizen' just goes away.

A workaround that might work for you, is having a .js/.html file locally within the widget that does the things you need it to do for you...and then having everything else load dynamically.  In our case, we had a local .html file do tizen.registerKey for our application, and then a window.onload redirect to our hosted solution.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. When I call a `tizen.` function from a `.js`  file in the root of my `.wgt`, it works; when I call the same function from a `.js` file in a subdirectory, it gives this namespace error.

Answer (score 2):

The `tizen` namespace is usually available only after the right privilege was declared in `config.xml`, same goes for any other of the API.

[This is how you declare the privileges](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/app_dev_process/specify_api_access.htm) or you can simply add this line:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tizen"/>
```

in `config.xml`,

Only after the privilege is set the Tizen Web Device API is instantiated (under the `window.tizen` namespace).

Similarly if you want to have the API available unde `window.tizen.download` namespace you need to have:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/download"/>
```

added in your privilege list in `config.xml`.

For a full list of the privileges use the IDE or check [this list](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/privilege.html).

Comment: it doesn't work even i have filled the above in the xml.

Comment: @AlanLee Things might gave change in the mean-time, try to use the IDE to add the privileges

Comment: Future readers, please note that http://tizen.org/privilege/tizen is already deprecated at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

What SDK version are you trying to use? I guess, here's a solution: http://www.mail-archive.com/general@lists.tizen.org/msg00092.html

Comment: feature is no longer used for allowing API/namespace usage, privilege is used instead, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually , you don't need to set privilege in config.xml for using tizen.application.xx API.

Without setting any privilege ,the code `tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit()` would run normally.

It may be temporary bug at Platform. As you know , Tizen is very unstable for now since is just growing.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable checkbutton "Enable Live Editing" in "Run Configurations" menu (rigth click on project -> "Run as" -> "Run configurations...")